# LiveAuthClient CanLogout always false?

Tags: windows, authorization, live, live-sdk, multiple-accounts

I ran into this issue just recently when I wanted to test my app with multiple live ids. I have an Azure Mobile Service that I use the live id with. Basically I remember being asked for whether the app can use my credentials or not at least once. Now the LiveAuthClient CanLogout variable is always false so I can't log my account out in order to sign in with another account.

I found some reference saying that I would need to remove some single sign on stuff by hand, but I could only find one thing in Credential Manager that was seemingly similar and removing it (MicrosoftAccount:sth) had no effect. Here's the relevant piece of my code:

```
        LiveAuthClient liveIdClient = new LiveAuthClient("myserviceredirecturi");
        LiveLoginResult liveAuthResult = await liveIdClient.InitializeAsync(new[] { "wl.basic" });

        if (liveIdClient.CanLogout)
            liveIdClient.Logout(); // Code never goes here, ever.

        LiveLoginResult liveLoginResult = await liveIdClient.LoginAsync(new[] { "wl.basic" });
```

The last line logs me in with the current windows 8 live id. How can I test with multiple live ids?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing here also. Been through http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh968445.aspx and various other bits of official documentation plus various blogs and other bits. Annoyingly none of it quite adds up to a coherent picture.